# How to use default request templates when using the serverless framework?

Tags: serverless-framework

I understand that I need to specify a request template for the API gateway in order to gain access to the request headers. [The Serverless docs](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#default-request-templates) say:

"Serverless ships with the following default request templates you can use out of the box:"

The default templates look like they provide access to what I want (i.e. request headers), but how do you tell Serverless to use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "default request templates you can use out of the box" are referring to a lambda integration, not a "default" integration, where you leave the parameter blank. If no integration is defined, then it is the default integration. So, under http, add "integration: lambda".

However, that being said, you should still have access to the headers when you do not specify the integration.

**Lambda Integration**
https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#example-lambda-event-before-customization

```
functions:
  create:
    handler: posts.create
    events:
      - http:
          path: posts/create
          method: post
          integration: lambda
```

**Default Integration**
https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#example-lambda-proxy-event-default

```
functions:
  index:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http: GET hello
```